# What is the significance of Sonya's discovery?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, secret-invasion

At the end of *Secret Invasion* (2023), there's a brief scene in which Sonya leads G'iah into a room containing

> hundreds of glowing, human-sized machines.

Nothing is explained about what these machines are, only that, in Sonya's words,

> This is how our enemy got so good.

They don't resemble the machines in which the impersonated humans (Everett Ross etc.) were being held, so I don't think that's what they're for. Even if they are, there's no mention of who these machines belong to (because they can't be Gravik's), who/what might be inside them, or... anything at all, really.

So what *are* these machines? Who do they belong to? Do we know, or is this a mystery to be resolved in a later MCU installment?

Comment: Those look like longer term storage for replaced humans where information might not need retrieval at short notice. There is no reason to assume that these aren't Gravik's.

Answer (score 3):

I did think the coverings over the humans looked a bit like the Widow’s Veil mask that Fury used to get through border control and meet Sonya in episode 5.

Sonya expressed surprise that a billion dollars of research only resulted in something capable of disguising a face; Nick said that the newer version worked on the whole body. Maybe Sonya got her hands on the newer version by the end of episode 6, and put it together with the memory-reading machine technology presumably recovered from Chernobyl.

Although the structure and orientation of the machines doesn’t match Gravik’s, the glowy-energy-tendril-thingies going into the subjects’ heads look pretty similar in both.

So, in short: some humans can now infiltrate almost as well as Skrulls can, and Olivia Colman is in charge of them.